# ASP.NET registration page: Can't insert data in sql database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, database

I'm working on an ASP.NET project which requires, a registration page. The following code verifies if the username or email address already exist, but if everything is ok it doesn't insert data into the database. What am I doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Drawing;

namespace BootstrapRegisterLogin
{
    public partial class SignUp : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        bool flag = false;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private String EncryptPassword(string pass)
        {
            pass = tbPass.Text;
            byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
            string EncryptedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            return EncryptedPassword;
        }   

        protected void btSignup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tbName.Text != "" && tbEmail.Text != "" && tbUname.Text != "" && tbPass.Text != "" && tbCPass.Text != "" && tbHoneypot.Text == "")
            {
                if (tbPass.Text == tbCPass.Text)
                {
                    String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabaseConectionString1"].ConnectionString;
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
                    {
                        con.Open();

                        SqlCommand verifica = new SqlCommand();
                        verifica.CommandText = "select * from [Users]";
                        verifica.Connection = con;

                        SqlDataReader rd = verifica.ExecuteReader();
                        while (rd.Read())
                        {
                            if (rd[1].ToString() == tbUname.Text || rd[3].ToString() == tbEmail.Text)
                            {
                                flag = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (flag == true)
                        {
                            if (rd[1].ToString() == tbUname.Text)
                            {
                                lblMsg.Text = "Username already exists!";
                            }

                            if (rd[3].ToString() == tbEmail.Text)
                            {
                                lblMsg.Text = "Email already exists in the database!";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Users values('" + tbUname.Text + "','" + EncryptPassword(tbPass.Text) + "','" + tbEmail.Text + "','" + tbName.Text + "','" + tbHoneypot.Text + "','U')", con);
                            //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            lblMsg.Text = "Congratulations! Registration complete!!";
                            lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lblMsg.Text = "The two passwords don't match!";
                }
            }
            else if (tbHoneypot.Text != "")
            {
                lblMsg.Text = "Sorry! Bots are not allowed!!";
            }
            else
            {
                lblMsg.Text = "All fields are required!!";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens? Do you see some kind of error message or are you redirected to the Login.aspx?

Comment: BTW: Make `flag` a local variable in `btSignup_Click` otherwise it won't be reset to false once you have entered an already existing username or password. You should also give it a more meaningful name.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Set breakpoints, step through your code, inspect your variables.

Comment: @NineBerry I tried making `flag` a local variable. I am redirected to Login.aspx but it still doesn't insert data in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncomment the line

```
//cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Without this line it can't work.

By the way, this:

```
SqlCommand verifica = new SqlCommand();
verifica.CommandText = "select * from [Users]";
verifica.Connection = con;

SqlDataReader rd = verifica.ExecuteReader();
while (rd.Read())
{
    if (rd[1].ToString() == tbUname.Text || rd[3].ToString() == tbEmail.Text)
    {
        flag = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (flag == true)
{
    if (rd[1].ToString() == tbUname.Text)
    {
        lblMsg.Text = "Username already exists!";
    }

    if (rd[3].ToString() == tbEmail.Text)
    {
        lblMsg.Text = "Email already exists in the database!";
    }
}
```

is a query that would be a lot more performant if it ran on the DBMS. You might want to change that to something like this:

```sql
SELECT [Username], [Email] 
FROM [Users] 
WHERE [Username] = @Username OR [Email] = @Email
```

And please use [SqlCommand.Prepare()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to prepare your queries instead of concating strings. The way you do this now, you are prone to [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

### UPDATE

Based on your update, your real problem is that `verifica` and `rd` are still using `con`. You need to dispose those, for example like this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
    con.Open();

    bool userNameExists = false;
    bool emailExists = false;

    using(SqlCommand verifica = new SqlCommand())
    {       
        //Update this query with the hints above
        verifica.CommandText = "select * from [Users]";
        verifica.Connection = con;

        using(SqlDataReader rd = verifica.ExecuteReader())
        {           
            while (rd.Read())
            {
                if (rd[1].ToString() == tbUname.Text)
                { 
                    userNameExists = true;
                    break;
                }
                else if (rd[3].ToString() == tbEmail.Text)
                {
                    emailExists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (userNameExists)
    {
        lblMsg.Text = "Username already exists!";
    }
    else if (emailExists)
    {
        lblMsg.Text = "Email already exists in the database!";
    }
    else
    {
        //You should update this part too, someone could choose the username 
        // "x','','U'); DROP TABLE [Users]; --" and do a lot of damage this way
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Users values('" + tbUname.Text + "','" + EncryptPassword(tbPass.Text) + "','" + tbEmail.Text + "','" + tbName.Text + "','" + tbHoneypot.Text + "','U')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        lblMsg.Text = "Congratulations! Registration complete!!";
        lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
    }
}
```

### WARNINGS

Image a user chooses the name `x','','U'); DROP TABLE [Users]; --`. What would happen in your query the way it is now?

`Convert.ToBase64String` is NOT *Encryption*. It is *Encoding* and can be reversed very easily. Use a *Hash* instead. In combination with the problem mentioned above, one could easily read the email address and passwords of all your users (and they certainly have other accounts with exactly that combination).

### Final Note

If simply uncommenting a line *solves* a problem but causes another, then you didn't fix it - you just caused another one.

In this case your original problem was

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Food for thought: Your `SqlDataReader` has a `Close` method.

Comment: If I uncomment that line i get the following:
`An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.`

Comment: Then that's your real problem, I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It works now.